# Using dashed curves but not affecting points

Tags: plotting

I have the following data:

```
logdata1 = {{2., 0.0372903}, {3., 0.0820386}, {4., 0.182722}, {4.9542, 0.372903}, {5.97728, 0.798006}, {6.96578, 2.16283}, {7.96578, 5.31386}, {8.96578, 11.6122}}
logdata2 = {{2., 0.0192395}, {3., Around[0.03184670184928928, 0.0024899193258395955`]}, {4., Around[0.12918694453212548`, 0.015717559334640346`]}, {4.9542, Around[0.3563997262004199, 0.08961820005530305]}, {5.97728, Around[0.9379541701984017, 0.28073501016321956`]}, {6.96578, Around[2.518491206905192, 0.31004473232138824`]}, {7.96578, Around[6.265246531528116, 0.8412886365140424]}, {8.96578, Around[11.733130869208633`, 1.2111257852990607`]}}
logdata3T = {{2., 0.0372903}, {3., 0.0820386}, {4., 0.182722}, {4.9542, 0.372903}, {5.97728, 0.772144}, {6.96578, 1.59279}, {7.96578, 3.22661}, {8.96578, 6.45695}}
logdata4E = {{2., 0.0192395}, {3., Around[0.03184670184928928, 0.0024899193258395955`]}, {4., Around[0.11936590592661056`, 0.007469757977518787]}, {4.9542, Around[0.30214121919217246`, 0.01680695544941727]}, {5.97728, Around[0.7423029972965487, 0.03672631005613403]}, {6.96578, Around[1.5032606475786903`, 0.07532005960664777]}, {7.96578, Around[3.069938162865453, 0.15313003853913512`]}, {8.96578, Around[6.199563008878771, 0.3087499964041098]}}
```

And the corresponding plot:

```
ListLinePlot[{logdata1, logdata2, logdata3T, logdata4E}, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", Frame -> True, 
PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.04}, LabelStyle -> {22, GrayLevel[0]}, 
PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}, {Red, Thick, Dashed}, {Blue, Thick, Dashed}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["M", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
Style["S", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, 
FrameTicks -> {{{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, None}, {{{2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8, 250}, {9, 500}}, None}}]
```

[image]

In the dashed curves, the data points have also became some sort of dashed, and they look ugly! How can I keep the points unchanged and only the curves to be dashed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plot markers have inherited the dashing specification from the plot style. You can override this by adding `Dashing[{}]` to the plot marker specification:

```
ListLinePlot[{logdata1, logdata2, logdata3T, logdata4E}, 
 IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", Frame -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Dashing[{}], Circle[]}}], 
   0.04}, LabelStyle -> {22, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
    Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}, {Red, 
    Thick, Dashed}, {Blue, Thick, Dashed}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["M", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
   Style["S", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, 
    None}, {{{2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8, 
      250}, {9, 500}}, None}}]
```

[image]